# Regex non-capturing parenthesis issue

Tags: regex

I have a database query which looks like this

```
select * from students join (select * from teachers) join (select * from workers
```

I had a requirement to tokenize this string based on 'select'.
I am trying regex `(select)(.*?)((?:select)|$)`, ut it is matching only 2 times.
Request some pointers on how to achieve this.

I need the 3 output tokens as below

- `select * from students join (`
- `select * from teachers) join  (`
- `select * from workers`

Comment: How the resulting tokens should look like?

Comment: What is the expected result? Please add it to your post.

Comment: In `(?:select)`, non-capturing parenthesis are useless... As probably are parenthesis in `(select)`. Why did you put them here?

Comment: @akoskm I need the 3 output tokens as below  1.select * from students join (  2.select * from teachers) join  (  3.select * from workers

Comment: What tool/language are you using to apply the regex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this regex will work:

```
select.*?(?=select|$)
```

The regex matches the word `select`, then any text (not including new lines) up until right before the next `select` or the end of the string.

Demonstration here: http://regex101.com/r/sR3gV1

Comment: Nice! If you make select.*? a capturing group you can see the three tokens: http://regex101.com/r/uZ8dP9

Comment: @jonas It really depends on how the regex is implemented. Given what Sushant has already, I don't think capturing groups are necessary.

Comment: Absolutely right, they aren't necessary. But in regex101 the result better visible... ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to parse the select queries from the string then you can use this regex. Assuming you are not doing select from multiple tables(i.e. not doing `select * from x,y,z`)

```
(select.*?from\\s+\\w+)
```